# Print scaling in pdfbox 1.8.10

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have existing PDF files that are full 8.5" x 11".  I'm trying to print them using pdfbox, but I can't seem to figure out how to scale them to the printable region for the printer. I'm using pdfbox-1.8.10.jar.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
          //  get PDF
          document = PDDocument.load( pdfFile );

          //  setup for printing
          PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
          printJob.setJobName(new File(pdfFile).getName());
          printJob.setPrintService(getPrinter(printerName));

                 //  print PDF
          printJob.setPageable(new PDPageable(document, printJob));
        printJob.print();

        //  success
        return "0";
```